# Swift function appears to be executing out of order

Tags: ios, swift

I have a created the method named `importStories()` which calls the `getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID` method to import timeline data from Twitter using the 3rd party library Swifter. The problem is that the method is returning before any values are set to twitterData. Any advice is appreciated.

```
func importStories() -> [String] {

    let twitterAccount = Swifter(REDACTED)

    var twitterData = [String]()

    twitterAccount.getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID("REDACTED", count: 0, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true, success: { (statuses) -> Void in
        if statuses != nil {
            for var i=0; i<statuses!.count; i++ {
                twitterData.append(statuses![i]["text"].string!)
            }
        }
    }) { (error) -> Void in

    }

    return twitterData
}


public func getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID(userID: String, count: Int?, sinceID: Int?, maxID: Int?, trimUser: Bool?, contributorDetails: Bool?, includeEntities: Bool?, success: ((statuses: [JSONValue]?) -> Void)?, failure: FailureHandler?) {
    var parameters: Dictionary<String, AnyObject> = ["user_id": userID]

    self.getTimelineAtPath("statuses/user_timeline.json", parameters: [:], count: count, sinceID: sinceID, maxID: maxID, trimUser: trimUser, contributorDetails: contributorDetails, includeEntities: includeEntities, success: success, failure: failure)
}
```

Comment: This is happening because getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID is an asynchronous method, meaning you call it, but you don't know when the result is coming back. One way to overcome this issue is using Delegation pattern(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern#Objective-C_example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pattern I use a lot. It can made to look nicer with some typealiases, but I didn't use any for this code.

The key here is to return the result by calling a block that is provided by the calling code.

```
func importStoriesWithSuccess(success:(result: [String]) -> Void, failure: (error: NSError) -> Void) {

    let twitterAccount = Swifter(REDACTED)

    var twitterData = [String]()

    twitterAccount.getStatusesUserTimelineWithUserID("REDACTED", count: 0, sinceID: nil, maxID: nil, trimUser: true, contributorDetails: false, includeEntities: true, success: { (statuses) -> Void in
        if statuses != nil {
            for var i=0; i<statuses!.count; i++ {
                twitterData.append(statuses![i]["text"].string!)
            }
            success(result: twitterData)
        }
        }) { (error) -> Void in
            failure(error: error)
    }
}
```

As cjcoax already mentioned, in your code twitterData is being returned before the twitterAccount executes the block you provided to it. That is why your twitterData is empty.